# Load external configuration in Spring not boot

Tags: angularjs, json, spring, configuration, external

I have a to load and share configuration between backend (spring 4, not spring boot) and frontend (angularjs) of an application using JSON format.

The external data (like application title, background-color, ...) have to be ready in the frontend when the server is started, and should be injected in the DB to make it possible to update it later.

Is it possible to do it (and how?) with my current used frameworks or should I migrate to spring boot to profit from its feature "Externalized Configuration"?

Thanks